# Returning list of objects inside S3 bucket using S3AsynClient and SdkPublisher

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, reactive-programming, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I am trying to retrive the list of contents inside the `S3 bucket` using `aws-java sdk 2` and `S3 async client`. However after running the below code, I dont see any output even though the bucket has one object inside it. Am I missing something here?

```
ListObjectsV2Request request = ListObjectsV2Request .builder().bucket("my-bucket").build();
ListObjectsV2Publisher response = s3AsyncClient.listObjectsV2Paginator(request);
response.contents().subscribe(s3object -> System.out.println(s3object));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the **S3AsyncClient** client to list objects in bucket using the **listObjectsV2** method, you can use this code (your Paginator call does not work for me either).

```
public static void listObjects(S3AsyncClient s3AsyncClient, String bucketName) {
        try {
            ListObjectsV2Request listReq = ListObjectsV2Request.builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .build();

            CompletableFuture<ListObjectsV2Response> future = s3AsyncClient.listObjectsV2(listReq);
            future.whenComplete((resp, err) -> {
                try {
                    if (resp != null) {
                        List<S3Object> objects = resp.contents();
                        for (S3Object myValue : objects) {
                            System.out.print("\n The name of the key is " + myValue.key());
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Handle error.
                        err.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } finally {
                    // Only close the client when you are completely done with it.
                    s3AsyncClient.close();
                }
            });
            future.join();

        } catch (S3Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Got my issue. The main thread was terminating before the subscription can begin. Added a thread.sleep() to find out.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out